# How do I get the elements row by row from a matrix in Racket?

Tags: racket

I'm making a simple Racket program where I input a matrix, and then I write on a single line on a file all the elements of the matrix, what I input is this:

```
(matrix[[1 2][3 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#lang racket

; [List-of [List-of Number]] -> [List-of Number]
; all elements of the matrix as a list
(define (print-matrix matrix)
  (apply append matrix))

; [List-of Nat] -> (void)
; prints the list with spaces in between
(define (print-list l)
  (match l
    ['() (void)]
    [(list e) (printf "~a" e)]
    [(cons f r) (printf "~a " f)
                (print-list (rest l))]))

; Matrix Sring -> (void)
; flattens and prints matrix to file
(define (flat-print-matrix matrix file)
  (with-output-to-file file
    (lambda () (print-list (print-matrix matrix)))))
```

**Summary**:  `print-matrix` appends all the rows together to collapse the matrix into one list. `print-list` prints that list on one list with spaces between the elements of the list. Finally `flat-print-matrix` composes the above two functions and directs the result onto a file. Evaluating `(flat-print-matrix '((1 2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9)) "somefile.txt")` will make a file called `somefile.txt` in the current directory with the following content: `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`.